# Why attach to a root ViewGroup when inflating a custom toast message?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

According to this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#java), when inflating a custom toast message, a root ViewGroup should be used, which is the layout in the xml file defining the custom toast message. The inflated view will be attached to this root:

```
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));
```

I do not understand the purpose of attaching the layout to the root ViewGroup, which is part of the layout. Why not use the attachToRoot flag as false:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, 
(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container), false);
```

By the way, my custom toast message works just fine even if I omit the root view and call inflate with 'null' as the second parameter. I understand that it might cause some issues with evaluating the LayoutParams, but I couldn't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Rule of Thumb

When you use the method `inflate()`, the third parameter has three options:

1. Passing `true`: That means, you are asking to ***attach*** the first parameter (view) in the `inflate()` method to the second parameter (i.e. ViewGroup).

   We use it in scenarios such that if you have a `Button` in one separate XML file that you want to attach to `Layout` (it could be your main one).

   **Example:**

   ```
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_button, myLinearLayout, true);
   ```
2. Passing `false`: That means, you are asking the `inflate()` method ***NOT*** to attach the first view to the second, but in this case, you have to add it yourself after.

   **Example:**

   ```
   Button button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_button, myLinearLayout, false);
   myLinearLayout.addView(button);
   ```

   It does the same like the first scenario, so no point of passing `false` here. However, there are scenarios when you ***should*** pass the third parameter as `false` such that when you are not the one responsible for attaching our layout file’s View to its root ViewGroup.

   **Example:**

   ```
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
       View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_item_recyclerView, parent, false);
       return new ViewHolder(view);
   }
   ```
3. Passing `null`:It is not recommended at all, however, your app won’t crash in this scenario, but it can misbehave. You app will try to determine the correct `LayoutParams` for the ***root `ViewGroup`*** by using the `generateDefaultLayoutParams`.
   (*which might not be what you desired*).

---

[For more details, refer to the source](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

---

### UPDATE

After reading your comment below, I see now where you get confused exactly with this matter:
You seem aware of the above rules, but your only confusion is: why we are passing a `View` as **root** to the *second* parameter in `inflate()` though it is ***already*** a **root** in the XML resource that we passed in the *first* parameter.

Well, that is in simple words because this is how `inflate()` method works:
Understanding **why** we need the ***second*** parameter in `inflate()` in general will solve this problem for you:

In addition to what I wrote above: The **second** parameter in `inflate()` is the root which is an *optional* view to be the **parent** of the generated hierarchy (if 3rd parameter is `true`), ***OR*** to be an ***OBJECT*** that ***PROVIDES*** the `LayoutParams` values for ***ROOT*** of the ***RETURNED*** hierarchy.

So `inflate()` method will ***always*** refer to the *second* parameter after generating the hierarchy of the view in the provided XML file at the first parameter.

---

### Conclusion

In your particular scenario, we are ***not*** passing `false` because that will lead to inflate call ***IGNORING*** the layout parameters from the ***XML***.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still don't understand what is the meaning of attaching a view to a viewgroup which is part of that same view (see the link in my question to the official android dev. page). It makes sense if you want to attach a separate xml, like you wrote, but in this case it's the same xml, and it looks like we're attaching something to itself.

Comment: Thank you again for your updated answer! It is clear now.